# Prove that $\int_{\frac{-f(0)}{M}}^{\frac{f(0)}{M}}f(x)\, dx \geq f(0)^{2}/M$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with bounded derivative. Assume that $|f'(x)|<M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)>0$. Then prove that $$\int_{\frac{-f(0)}{M}}^{\frac{f(0)}{M}}f(x)\, dx \geq \frac{f(0)^2}{M}$$

The only result i know is the mean value theorem which asserts $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. But I don't think it can be used here. I am completely out of ideas. A detailed solution would prove helpful.

Comment: Try to show $f(x)\ge f(0)-Mx$ using MVT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Mean Value Theorem

$$\vert f(x) - f(0) \vert \le M \vert x \vert$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Therefore

$$-M \vert x \vert + f(0) \le f(x) \le M \vert x \vert + f(0)$$ and by integration over the interval $[- \frac{f(0)}{M},\frac{f(0)}{M}]$

$$3\frac{f(0)^2}{M} \ge\int_{- \frac{f(0)}{M}}^{\frac{f(0)}{M}} f(x) \ dx \ge 2 \frac{f(0)^2}{M} - \frac{f(0)^2}{M} = \frac{f(0)^2}{M}$$ as desired.